# Angular app in a third-party website

Tags: angularjs, widget

I am developing a widget in angular that may be embedded in a third-party website. As I don't know if my widget may be embedded to a website that is already loading angular I have to take care of it.

After some research I made it to run two versions of angular in the same webpage. The issue comes because my widget will be doing manual bootstrapping while, I guess, the client site will be doing auto bootstrapping. Here it is when an error displays.

```
    angular.js:78 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module appHost due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'appHost' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.29/$injector/nomod?p0=appHost
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.29/angular.js:78:12
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.29/angular.js:1679:17
```

It seems that the second version of angular is trying to bootstrap a module from the first version (the client's one). Anyway it works but I can't let that error display in the client website. I don't know if there is a better way to encapsulate/isolate my code.

I created this [example in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sr3rvbmxCbVQi2Q1FaIu?p=preview) in order you can see what I am talking about. Any idea about how to avoid that error? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the error in the plunker...